# Datamapper, use yaml for configuration

Tags: heroku, sinatra, datamapper

I have a Sinatra app which uses DataMapper as it's ORM, it's deployed to Heroku, but I want to change the database details.

Right now before my Models, I'm connecting to my DB like this, but I want to use a `yml` file to manage the connections details.

```
DataMapper.setup(:default, ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || "sqlite3::memory:")
```

If I have a file thats at `config/database.yml`, how can I change the `DataMapper.setup` to use the proper ENV? This way I can remove the need for `sqlite3` as I'll be running Postgres locally too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, DataMapper doesn't parse `.yml`. You can look at https://github.com/merb/merb_datamapper/blob/master/lib/merb_datamapper/connection.rb to see how `.yml` config is consumed in Merb framework.